# How to calculate equal hash for similar strings?

Tags: hash, levenshtein-distance

I create Antiplagiat. I use a shingle method. For example, I have the following shingles:

1. I go to the cinema
2. I go to the cinema1
3. I go to th cinema

Is there a method of calculating the equal hash for these lines?

I know of the existence of Levenshtein distance. However, I do not know what I should take source word. Maybe there is a better way than to consider Levenshtein distance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with hashing is that, logically, you'll run into 2 strings that differ by a single character that hash to different values.

**Small proof:**

Consider all possible strings.
Assume all of these hash to at least 2 different values.
Take any 2 strings A and B that hash to different values.
You can obviously go from A to B by just changing one character at a time.
Thus at some point the hash will change.
Thus at this point the hash will be different for a single character change.

**Some options I can think of:**

- Hash multiple parts of the string and check each of these hashes. Probably won't work too well since a single character omission will cause significant difference in the hash values.
- Check a range of hashes. A hash is one dimensional, but string similarity is not, thus this probably won't work either.

All in all, hashing is probably not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This questions is a bit old but you may be interested in [this paper](http://isis.poly.edu/~baris/papers/conference/smsSpam-ICC12.pdf) by two researchers at AT&T.   They employ a technique that is reminiscent of the Nilsimsa hash to detect when similar sms messages have been seen an "abnormal" number of times in a time window.

It sounds [Locality Sensitive hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) would also be pertinent to your problem.

Comment: Can you add the relevant section of the link you provided to the answer? It's always better if you can (please visit [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._