# Dictionary hash function for fuzzy lookups

Tags: c#, dictionary, hash, hashtable, fuzzy-search

When an approximated comparison between strings is required, the basic [Levenshtein Distance](https://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein) can help. It measures the amount of modifications of the string needed to equal another string:

```
"aaaa" vs "aaab" => 1
"abba" vs "aabb" => 2
"aaaa" vs "a"    => 3
```

When using a `Dictionary<T, U>` one can provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`. One can implement the Levenshtein Distance as an `IEqualityComparer<string>`:

```
public class LevenshteinStringComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    private readonly int _maximumDistance;

    public LevenshteinStringComparer(int maximumDistance)
        => _maximumDistance = maximumDistance;

    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
        => ComputeLevenshteinDistance(x, y) <= _maximumDistance;

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
        => 0;

    private static int ComputeLevenshteinDistance(string s, string t)
    {
        // Omitted for simplicity
        // Example can be found here: https://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein
    }
}
```

So we can use a fuzzy dictionary:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>(new LevenshteinStringComparer(2));
dict["aaa"] = 1;
dict["aab"] = 2; // Modify existing value under "aaa" key

// Only one key was created:
dict.Keys => { "aaa" }
```

Having all this set up, you may have noticed that we don't have implemented a proper `GetHashCode` in the `LevenshteinStringComparer` which would be greatly appreciated by the dictionary. As some rule of thumbs regarding hash codes, I'd use:

- Unequal objects **should** not have the same hash code
- Equal objects **must** have the same hash code

The only possible hash function following these rules I can imagine is a constant number, just as implemented in the given code. This isn't optimal though, but when we start for example to take the default hash of the string, then `aaa` and `aab` would end up with different hashes, even though they are handled as equal. Thinking further this means all possible strings have to have the same hash.

**Am I correct?** And why does the performance of the dictionary gets better when I use the default string hash function with hash collisions for our comparer? **Shouldn't this make the hash buckets inside the dictionary invalid?**

```
public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    => obj.GetHashCode();
```

Comment: I see a problem here. If you allow distance 1 and have an item with 'aab' already, adding 'aaa' or 'abb' results the same, but if the first item is 'abb', the final outcome is different.

Comment: This reminds me of [Ring Species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_species) - the idea that as species of animals that live in adjacent areas can still mate, when you go around a large obstacle, like a mountain range or an ocean, you can end up having the final two animals at each end of the ring unable to mate. At what point do two animals cease being the same species and become different ones? Same with your keys. I could start with two keys that you'd count as not the same, yet I could find a series of intermediate keys that would be considered a match to join the first two together.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, but I think this discussion relates... 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377043/how-to-calculate-equal-hash-for-similar-strings

Comment: @PepitoSh Yes, this dictionary is weird in quite some ways, but is what you mention violating some specific implementation rule we should follow?

Comment: Not at all. My world is more deterministic and I cannot see a good use of this type of dictionary. Maybe if you brought some potential use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a hashing function that could work in your case.

The problem is that you have to assign the bucket based on a signle value only, while you can't know what was added before. But the Levenshtein distance of the item being hashed can be anything from 0 to "infinity", only thing that matters is what it is compared with. Hence you cannot satisfy the second condition of the hashing function (to have equal objects have the same hash code).

Another argument *"pseudo-proof"* would be the situation when you want **maximum distance of 2** and you already have **two items in the dictionary**, which have mutual **distance of 3**. If you then add a string which is of distance 2 from the first item and distance 1 from the second item, how would you decide which item should it match to? It satisfies your maximum for both items, but it should probably match with the second one rather than the first one. But **not knowing anything about the contents** of the dictionary you cannot know how to hash it correctly.

For the second question - using the default `string.GetHashCode()` method does improve performance, but it destroys the functionality of your equality comparer. If you test this solution on your sample code, you can see that the `dict` will contain two keys now. This is because `GetHashCode` returned two different hash codes, so there was no conflict and `dict` now has two buckets and your `Equals` method was not even executed.

Comment: Oh yeah, haven't checked the dictionary keys that were created when using the string hash function. Great answer btw

Comment: Glad it helped :-). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I can understand fuzzy lookup. But not fuzzy storage. Why would you want to overwrite "aaa" when assigning a value for "aab"?  If all you want is fuzzy lookup wouldn't it be better to have a normal dictionary which has an extension to do a fuzzy lookup like...

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> FuzzyMatch<T>(this IDictionary<string, T> dictionary, string key, int distance = 2)
    {
        IEqualityComparer<string> comparer = new LevenshteinStringComparer(distance);

        return dictionary
            .Keys
            .Where(k => comparer.Equals(k, key))
            .Select(k => dictionary[k]);
    }
}
```

This is more of a comment than an answer.  To answer your question, if you consider the following example...

```
"abba" vs "cbbc" => 2
"cddc" vs "cbbc" => 2
"abba" vs "cddc" => 4
```

You get the gist here?  i.e Clearly its not possible for the following to be true

```
abba == cbbc && 
cddc == cbbc &&
abba != cddc
```

Answer (score 0):

The only strict rule is that if objects are equal then they should have the same hashcode which is guaranteed by returning 0. In this case you always fallback to Equals.

Levenshtein distance can be normalized to 1.0.

The only issue is that results depend on order of adding items, some similar values may end up in different buckets. It is ok in cases when words are mostly "far" from each other, it allows you to lower criteria, eg `Better`, `Beter`, `Beetter`, `Knowledge`, `Programming`.

Results can be better if you apply some clustering algorithm first and use cluster as a key.

Comment: "The only strict rule is [...]" No, that's *not* the only strict rule.  There are others, such as `Equals` being transitive, which this isn't, and is the nature of the problem.

Comment: I don't see any contradiction, I mentioned that lookups depend on order, it means lack of transitivity.

Comment: You don't see a contradiction in saying there's only one rule, when there's other rules?

Comment: This rule is enough for dictionary to work, lack of transitivity is mentioned, which part is not clear to you?

Comment: But it *doesn't* work, because there *are* other rules that are needed for it to work, such as equality being transitive.  Saying, "it'll work if you do this, but unless you do a bunch of other things it'll produce the wrong output" makes no sense.  You need to do *all* of the things for it to work, not just the one you claim is the only one.  And of course there are other rules it needs to follow you didn't mention, such as equality being symmetric, consistent, etc.

Comment: I literally provided an example when it will work good enough, you may choose not to see it but I'm done.

Comment: So because it works with one specific example, even though it doesn't work with tons of other examples, it's not a rule and it doesn't matter that it doesn't work because it's not the one example you provided?  What are you even saying?  Do you think that those 5 specific values are the only values that will ever be used?  Just telling someone "I'm not wrong as long as you don't use any of the values that produce the wrong output and only use the one value that coincidentally works" is...something all right.